# How to display base64 image? URI Too Long

Tags: php, symfony, base64

I have code (below) to display an image stored as base64:

```
{% if question['image'] != '' %}
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4">
            <img src="{{ question['image'] }}" />
        </td>
    </tr>
{% endif %}
```

However, it will not load due to this error:

```
Request-URI Too Long
The requested URL's length exceeds the capacity limit for this server.
```

How can I get around this error?

I'd prefer to do something in PHP (maybe temporarily store the image and save it as a file on the server?) rather than change Apache settings.

But any ideas are welcome.

Comment: this doesn't look like php code...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Never mind, I just realised my mistake. The URL for the image needed to be this:

```
src="data:image/jpeg;base64,{{ question['image'] }}"
```

I didn't have the `data:image/jpeg;base64,` before.

Hopefully this helps someone else how has the same problem one day!